# How to locate a file containing specific class name in magento?

Tags: html, magento, templates, themes, root

I am new to magento and need your help to locate a file/template in magento directory? I want to locate the template which contains the code for "Featured Category" section on home page of http://woodfordtooling.com/. I need to make some changes in this section but not able to locate the template. I have tried with Pathy hints On but it's not telling me the template path for this section.

I can see the class name for these boxes by inspect element. The one class name is item_box item_box2.

Please help me to locate this.

Comment: Please check your CMS home page may be featured category section coming from static block

Answer (score 0):

Open your app/design/frontend/theme/template/ folder and search in there for some of the class names. If nothing turns up, it may not be dynamic and may be being added in the CMS.

So login to your backend, navigate to the homepage and take a look at the content. It may be in the content, referenced in a static block or a template file there.